# socket close inside fork c++

Tags: c++, unix-socket

I am trying socket programming and with the server code:

```
    while(1) {
    sin_size = sizeof (their_addr);
    new_fd = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
    if(new_fd == -1) {
        perror("accept");
        continue;
    }

    inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr*)&their_addr),s,sizeof(s));
    cout<<"got connection from" << s << endl;

    if((pid = fork()) == 0){//child
        close(sockfd);
        if(send(new_fd,"hello world!",12,0) == -1) {
            perror("send");
            close(new_fd);
            exit(0);
        }
        char buf[50];
        int numbytes;
        if((numbytes = recv(new_fd,&buf,50,0)) == -1) {
            perror("receive");
            close(new_fd);
            exit(0);
        }
        buf[numbytes] = '\0';
        cout<<"numbytes" << numbytes <<endl;
        cout<<"server received " << buf <<endl;
    }
    close(new_fd);
}
```

this code gives me a bad file descriptor, however when i comment the close(sockfd),
the code runs fine. Since I am forking to a new child process and closing the listening port , why am I getting a bad file descriptor? Is there something I am missing here.

Comment: I'm assuming that `sockfd` is the passive listening socket, and `new_fd` is a newly accepted socket?

Comment: yes that is indeed the case

Comment: _Where_ are you getting the "bad file descriptor" error? Which call?

Comment: i guess it is at the recv part since I get hello world on the client

Comment: You _guess_ it's the receive part? Do you get the `perror` output from there? Add error checking to the `close` calls as well.

Comment: i tried debugging the child process from gdb and it there was no error there. What is my guess is that when i close the sockfd from the client, it gets closed for the parent process as well leading to bad file descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

You close `new_fd` *twice*. After you receive you close it once, then the child process continues and close it again. You should put that second `close` only in the parent process, or not close at all inside the `if (fork())` body.

Comment: i changed that to only closing the new_fd in parent, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is almost 2 years since the question was posed, but I had the same issue, and after googling around and not finding anything I decided to try working on it for a while. I found the issue to be that you don't close the child process unless there's a send error. So instead of having this:

```cpp
if (send(new_fd,"hello world!",12,0) == -1) {
    perror("send");
    close(new_fd);
    exit(0);
}
```

Move the closing bracket right below the perror like this:

```cpp
if (send(new_fd,"hello world!",12,0) == -1) {
    perror("send");
}    
close(new_fd);
exit(0);
```

By doing this, you force the child process to close right after sending the message. I'm not entirely sure, but I think that the Bad file descriptor comes from the call to accept, by the forked child process, which hasn't been closed but has a Bad file descriptor, since you've closed the listening socket for this process.